# data from text field won't get stored into my field variable

Tags: java, swing, listener

I did all what I could, I've tried to register the textfields with actionlistener and used getsource, the variable I try to store the data from the textfield still comes up with null, then tried to get the data through the press of a button registering my buttons with actionlistener but the variable still comes up with null, what am I doing wrong?

```
package stackovtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class StackovTest extends JFrame {

public StackovTest()
{
    super ("FNA");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setResizable(false);
    stackOVClass comps = new stackOVClass();
    add(comps);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            new StackovTest();
        }
    });
   }   
}


package stackovtest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;


public class stackOVClass extends JPanel {

 // variable declarations
private final JLabel pLabel;
private final JTextField pTextField; 

private final JLabel newbLabel;
private final JTextField newbTextField;

private final JButton changeButton;

private final JTextArea dispTextArea;

// end of variable declarations

public stackOVClass()
{
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

    Color code = new Color(0, 255, 255);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(code);


    /////////// COLUMN 1//////////////

    pLabel = new JLabel("Policy #");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
    add(pLabel, gbc);

    newbLabel = new JLabel("NB Date:");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    add(newbLabel, gbc);

    ////////// COLUMN 2 ///////////

    pTextField = new JTextField(20);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    pTextField.setBorder(border);
    add(pTextField, gbc);

    newbTextField = new JTextField(20);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    newbTextField.setBorder(border);
    add(newbTextField, gbc);

    changeButton = new JButton("Change");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.weightx = 0.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    add(changeButton, gbc);
    ///////////////////// TEXT AREA ///////////////////////

    dispTextArea = new JTextArea();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 6;
    gbc.gridwidth = 9;
    gbc.gridheight = 4;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    dispTextArea.setEditable(true);
    dispTextArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    dispTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    dispTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(dispTextArea);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 120));
    scroll.setBorder(border);
    add(scroll, gbc);

    CompHandler compHandler = new CompHandler();
    changeButton.addActionListener(compHandler);

   }



    // class to handle text fields
    private class CompHandler implements ActionListener 
    {
        private String pNum;
        private String newbDate;
        private final String change = "See new premium change. ";
        private final String decrease = "See new premium decrease. ";
        private final String increase = "See new premium increase. ";
        private final String comment = "() Policy Number (" + pNum + ") validated prior insurance effective (" + newbDate + ") per documentation in Image Center." 
                                         + "Verified prior BI Limits of () with () days lapse in coverage. ";

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            Object button_command = e.getActionCommand();

            if (button_command.equals("Change"))
            {
                pNum = pTextField.getText();
                newbDate = newbTextField.getText();

                dispTextArea.setText(comment + change);
            }
        }
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates

    } // end component handler class
```

}

this should run it was properly tested... I'd love some advice with this, or some better way I could implement my code

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the pNum and newbDate Strings to another String while their still null. Then you change pNum and newbDate to hold values, but the other String won't change nor should it change. Strings are immutable, and even if they were mutable, objects dont' change by magic, you have to set the String variables with new updated data for the data to show.

In a nut shell this is what you're doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String foo = null;
  String bar = null;
  String baz = "foo: " + foo + "; bar: " + bar;

  foo = "FOO";
  bar = "BAR";

  System.out.println(baz);
}
```

This returns:

```
foo: null; bar: null
```

Please understand that the String baz won't change by magic just because you've changed foo and bar **after** the fact. If you want baz to change, **you** need to change it when the need arises:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String foo = null;
  String bar = null;
  String baz = "foo: " + foo + "; bar: " + bar;

  foo = "FOO";
  bar = "BAR";

  // change baz with new data
  baz = "foo: " + foo + "; bar: " + bar;

  System.out.println(baz);  // now this works!
}
```

Comment: THANKS MAJORLY hovercraft.. i don't even know how to thank you it did work.. thanks alot...

Comment: @Juice: you're welcome, but most important is whether you understand now why it didn't work.

Comment: Yes i did.. and that was something i should have figured out cause i did do the same thing the correct way in another project.. everything just came back to me as u explained what i was doing.. but thanks alot

Comment: @Juice: good, because that's what really matters. Glad you're moving forward.